# java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can either send form parameters OR body content in POST, not both

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am pretty new to restassured for post request i am getting below error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can either send form parameters OR body content in POST, not both!

Here is my test

```
public void createModel() {
                        
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
        obj2.put("name", "hello1234");
        List<JSONObject> list1 = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        list1.add(obj2);
        System.out.println(" i am list 1   " + list1);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("modes", list1);
        System.out.println("i am a object \n" + obj.toString());
        System.out.println("testtest " + obj);
        
        Response response = httpRequest.auth().preemptive().basic("test", "test")
                .given().contentType("application/json").body(obj.toString()).when().post("/modes").then().using()
                .extract().response();
        int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
        System.out.println(statusCode + " this is post");           
        System.out.println("This is body" + response.getBody().prettyPrint());
        
    }
```

I am using RestAssured 3.0.2 dependency
It was really working fine suddenly it giving error, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Add `log().all()` after `given()` and paste the output here, and is this the complete code ? what is with `httpRequest`  and also why are you on 3.0.2 when the latest is 4.3.0 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.Param` for POST will default to form parameters, so you need to explicitly mention it as `.queryParam`

```
given().
        queryParam("name, "asdasdh).
        body(..).
when().
```